# is there a way to concatenate strings in mysql where any of the strings may be null?

Tags: mysql

I need to concatenate a couple of dozen strings into one string and the concat function returns a null if any of the strings are null. is there a function that ignores nulls in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) which skips nulls:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'string 1', NULL, 'string 2')
-- string 1 string 2
```

You can use `''` as the separator, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` operator for this as `COALESCE(yourString, '')`, this will return your string if not null or an empty string it it's null.

From the docs:
Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce